# Anti-Join causing Slow Nested-Loop and Gather Merge

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, optimization

I have a complex query in my application that is hitting many, many more rows than I expect. I have individual indices on every field that is involved in a comparison, and it isn't clear to me what the reason is that so many rows are being looked at. I can provide the full SQL for my migrations to set up this schema if that helps. My Postgres version is `PostgreSQL 13.6 (Ubuntu 13.6-1.pgdg20.04+1+b1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, 64-bit` and my query is as follows:

```sql
select distinct
    on ("date"."on_date") "from"."id",
                          "from"."uri",
                          "from"."title",
                          "linkage"."id",
                          "linkage"."from_topic",
                          "linkage"."to_topic",
                          "linkage"."title",
                          "to"."id",
                          "to"."uri",
                          "to"."title",
                          "date"."linkage",
                          "date"."on_date",
                          1 as "clustering_level"
from "memo"."linkages" as "linkage"
         join "memo"."topics" as "from"
              on "linkage"."from_topic" = "from"."id"
         join "memo"."topics" as "to" on "linkage"."to_topic" = "to"."id"
         join "memo"."dates" as "date" on "linkage"."id" = "date"."linkage"
         join "memo"."topic_clusters_extralarge" on "to"."id" = "memo"."topic_clusters_extralarge"."topic_id"
where ("memo"."topic_clusters_extralarge"."cluster_id" = 644190
    and "to"."id" <> 3494419
    and "to"."id" <> 3494419
    and not (exists(select "other_linkage"."id"
                    from "memo"."linkages" as "other_linkage"
                             join "memo"."topics" as "other_from" on "other_linkage"."from_topic" = "other_from"."id"
                             join "memo"."topics" as "other_to" on "other_linkage"."to_topic" = "other_to"."id"
                             join "memo"."dates" as "other_date" on "other_linkage"."id" = "other_date"."linkage"
                    where ("other_from"."id" = 3494419
                        and "other_to"."id" = 3494419
                        and "other_linkage"."title" = 'founding date'
                        and "other_date"."on_date" = "date"."on_date")))) fetch next 3 rows only;
```

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) output:

```
Limit  (cost=1014.89..13839.83 rows=3 width=198) (actual time=212.116..272.031 rows=3 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=167086 read=48469
  ->  Unique  (cost=1014.89..13330409.64 rows=3118 width=198) (actual time=212.115..272.028 rows=3 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=167086 read=48469
        ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=1014.89..13330401.85 rows=3118 width=198) (actual time=212.113..272.019 rows=3 loops=1)
              Join Filter: (other_date.on_date = date.on_date)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3
              Buffers: shared hit=167086 read=48469
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1002.18..13330322.27 rows=3118 width=194) (actual time=211.960..271.856 rows=3 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=167081 read=48455
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1001.75..13317470.44 rows=3118 width=120) (actual time=211.953..271.839 rows=3 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=167069 read=48455
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1001.32..13303707.50 rows=3335 width=54) (actual time=211.923..271.768 rows=3 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=167066 read=48446
                                ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.89..6380360.44 rows=1695493 width=46) (actual time=43.693..87.676 rows=23344 loops=1)
                                      Workers Planned: 2
                                      Workers Launched: 2
                                      Buffers: shared hit=97570 read=24566
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..6183658.45 rows=706455 width=46) (actual time=0.090..87.146 rows=8137 loops=3)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=97570 read=24566
                                            ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_memo_dates_on_date on dates date  (cost=0.43..3087744.73 rows=706455 width=12) (actual time=0.032..25.898 rows=8137 loops=3)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=14740 read=9746
                                            ->  Index Scan using linkages_pkey on linkages linkage  (cost=0.44..4.38 rows=1 width=34) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=24412)
                                                  Index Cond: (id = date.linkage)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=82830 read=14820
                                ->  Index Scan using idx_memo_topic_clusters_extralarge_topic_id on topic_clusters_extralarge  (cost=0.43..4.07 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=23344)
                                      Index Cond: (topic_id = linkage.to_topic)
                                      Filter: (cluster_id = 644190)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                      Buffers: shared hit=69496 read=23880
"                          ->  Index Scan using topics_pkey on topics ""to""  (cost=0.43..4.13 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=1 loops=3)"
                                Index Cond: (id = linkage.to_topic)
                                Filter: ((id <> 3494419) AND (id <> 3494419))
                                Buffers: shared hit=3 read=9
"                    ->  Index Scan using topics_pkey on topics ""from""  (cost=0.43..4.12 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=3)"
                          Index Cond: (id = linkage.from_topic)
                          Buffers: shared hit=12
              ->  Materialize  (cost=12.71..32.81 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.049..0.052 rows=1 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=5 read=14
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=12.71..32.81 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.142..0.149 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=5 read=14
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=12.28..24.35 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.118..0.123 rows=1 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=5 read=10
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=11.85..19.90 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.112..0.116 rows=1 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=1 read=10
                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on linkages other_linkage  (cost=11.42..15.44 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.088..0.090 rows=1 loops=1)
                                            Recheck Cond: ((from_topic = 3494419) AND (to_topic = 3494419))
                                            Filter: (title = 'founding date'::text)
                                            Heap Blocks: exact=1
                                            Buffers: shared read=7
                                            ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=11.42..11.42 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.077..0.078 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                  Buffers: shared read=6
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_memo_linkages_from_topic  (cost=0.00..4.51 rows=10 width=0) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=10 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: (from_topic = 3494419)
                                                        Buffers: shared read=3
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_memo_linkages_to_topic  (cost=0.00..6.66 rows=296 width=0) (actual time=0.054..0.054 rows=4 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: (to_topic = 3494419)
                                                        Buffers: shared read=3
                                      ->  Index Only Scan using topics_pkey on topics other_from  (cost=0.43..4.45 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: (id = 3494419)
                                            Heap Fetches: 0
                                            Buffers: shared hit=1 read=3
                                ->  Index Only Scan using topics_pkey on topics other_to  (cost=0.43..4.45 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (id = 3494419)
                                      Heap Fetches: 0
                                      Buffers: shared hit=4
                          ->  Index Scan using idx_memo_dates_linkage on dates other_date  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.022..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (linkage = other_linkage.id)
                                Buffers: shared read=4
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=99 read=33
Planning Time: 2.455 ms
Execution Time: 272.119 ms
```

Comment: What do you think it should be doing instead?  What explain output do you get if you run the same query without the limit?

Comment: Why is `"to"."id" <> 3494419` present twice?  Is one of those supposed to be "from"?

Answer (score 0):

Very little of your time is going to the anti-join.  Maybe the NOT EXISTS is fundamentally changing the structure of the query plan, but I kind of doubt that too.  I don't think this has anything to do with the anti-join.  You could always just the same query without the NOT EXISTS part and see what it does.

2/3 of your time is going to this:

```
->  Index Scan using idx_memo_topic_clusters_extralarge_topic_id on topic_clusters_extralarge  (cost=0.43..4.07 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=23344)
      Index Cond: (topic_id = linkage.to_topic)
      Filter: (cluster_id = 644190)
      Rows Removed by Filter: 1
      Buffers: shared hit=69496 read=23880
```

Since buffers read is almost equal to loops, I'm guessing that the index is almost entirely in shared_buffers, and almost all of the time is going to reading the page in the table with the row having a specific topic_id, only to discover that that row has the wrong cluster_id and so fails the join.  If it could determine this just from the index, it wouldn't need to read a bunch of random table pages only to fail.  So if the index were on `(topic_id, cluster_id)` or probably better `(cluster_id, topic_id)`, it should save you a lot of time.

There maybe other issues going on as well, but we don't have enough information to know about them.  Like, why is the Gather Merge where it is instead of being 3 levels of Nested Loop up?  And why not just read all the rows and then sort them--that could be much better, or could be much worse.  Or of course, about the same.